# Regex for search and replace in Calc

Tags: regex, openoffice-calc

My data is in Column A, starting from A1 has data in the following pattern.

```
1.2.3.4:10.abc.something.mydata.somethingelse
```

The pattern will contain an ip address followed by port number and words seperated by four dots. I want to search for the pattern and replace the data in each cell with 'mydata', ie the word after ip address and port, then after two dots. How can we do this using the search and replace option regex in Open office calc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for : `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+:[0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z0-9]+)\.[a-z0-9]+`

and replace by : `$1`